# check if a player got banned, kicked or just left the server

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to know how to get the kick reason and find out if the user left got kicked or got banned

```
client.on('guildMemberRemove', async(member) => {
      if(member == left){
          console.log(member.user.tag + "left the server")
      }else if(member == kicked){
          console.log(member.user.tag + "got kicked from the server the server bacause, "+reason)
      }else if(member == banned){
          console.log(member.user.tag + "got banned from the server the server bacause, "+reason)
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the members getting banned, you can track them with [`guildBanAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildBanAdd) event, and [`Guild.fetchBan(user)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchBan) returns [`BanInfo`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/typedef/BanInfo) including the reason they banned.

However for the kicked member, there seems to be no other way than checking Guild's Audit logs. As far as I read the documentation, unfortunately, Discord.js has no events that tracks the Audit logs, so you have to call [`Guild.fetchAuditLogs([options])`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchAuditLogs) in `guildMemberRemove` event like [this](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/audit-logs.html#who-kicked-a-user).